# Does async/await need a thread to signal the async operation is done?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I try to figure out how does async/await works for continuation.

For example I take a simple console with only a `Task.Delay`.

I have the following threads:

[image]

It continues on the same thread (main thread) but there is another worker thread at the location

```
mscorlib.dll! System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncCausalityTracer.TraceSynchronousWorkCompletion
```

is it responsible to trigger the continuation on the main thread?
I always wondered how the code can continue after an await.

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: @JSteward I am not sure about you, but I can clearly see another thread in the screenshot. The link only applies to "real" asynchronous code, as the post starts saying.

Comment: Yup there is another thread there. That post seemed the best way to address this OP comment: _I always wondered how the code can continue after an await._

Comment: The thread appears to have a diagnostic function; it helps debug asynchronous flows of operation. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.diagnostics.asynccausalitytracer. Note that that links to a Windows API documentation; the .net documentation of System.Threading.Tasks (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks?view=netcore-2.1) does not have such a class but I'd be surprised if that wasn't just a thin .net layer for the Windows API. So: No, the thread is not necessary for functionality, it's a diagnostic tracer, as the name suggests.

Comment: But, if you consider the case where Main was marked async, and you awaited the Task.Delay...  I'm pretty sure (though not absolutely sure), that the delay would run on a separate thread, and then, when it completed, it would marshal control back to the main thread, to the _continuation_ that contains the rest of the Main function.  How it does that marshaling depends on what kind of application you have.  Best places to learn this stuff: Stephen Cleary's and Stephen Toub;s blogs, @EricLippert 's blog's series on continuation-based programming and the MSDN mag's article introducing async/await.

Comment: @Flydog57 Neither of those things is true.  The delay is not representing code running on a thread.  There is no "other thread" to run it.  The continuation won't run on the main thread; there is no mechanism by which it could run the continuation, as such a framework needs to be put in place by yourself, and you haven't done that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was curious about how that would work; I've only ever used async/await in an environment where there was enough context to get all this working (the WinForms post to UI thread mechanism, or the WPF dispatcher, as examples).  I don't often write console apps.

Comment: Hello all, first thanks for your answers I really appreciate it. It seems it is not really documented. Also it seems to depend on the application context (console, winform, wpf, asp.net etc). It looks like async/await is an abstract concept which helps to have the same code form (using async and await) but behind the scenes it can be complex and implementation dependent.